# HttpClient hangs while authenticating

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-authentication

I'm writing a Java program that connects to a web server (HTTPS and requires username/password) with this code, but it hangs when it reaches the `execute` call:

```
KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("D:/jssecacerts"));
try {
    trustStore.load(instream, "certspassword".toCharArray());
} finally {
    try { instream.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
}

SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory);
httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://server/path/default.aspx");

httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope("server", 443),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pass"));

System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

This is what I've tried in order to isolate the problem:

- If I comment out the `setCredentials` line, it doesn't hang and the server instantly returns a `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` response
- It doesn't matter if I provide a valid username/password or not
- I've tried to specify timeouts with different methods but it remains hung after the timeout interval is over

Comment: Could you provide a wire / context log of the session exhibiting the problem?

Comment: I can't get a wire log because the data is encrypted (is that what you meant?)

Comment: HttpClient can log a fair amount of useful contextual details. Besides, it can log content transferred across the wire before and after its encryption / decryption. Please see http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html for instructions

Comment: After setting up logging with those instructions I found out that it was also a 401 Unauthorized response, as I was using username instead of DOMAIN/username. Thanks!